# What's the significance of Razor's ability to pass a template to a method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I've seen it referenced a couple times now - most recently in [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/11/12/razor-template-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx):

```
Also using Razor template you can pass template as a parameter to a method.
```

It would be helpful to hear about the real-life problems this ability solves.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ability is a natural effect of how Razor actually works. It's something that's available because Razor requires this capability internally.

For a real-life example take a look at my blog post on [Razor sections with default content](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2010/12/08/optional-razor-sections-with-default-content.aspx). You can use it to write the following code:

```
@this.RenderSection("OptionalSection", @<div>Default Content</div>)
```

Comment: regarding '@<div>' ... as displayed this is coded html - a div...would that be a typical usage? It's intended to be a short label in the absence of real content? I'm struggling to get my head around razor's mix of content and script.